# Spring Data - No property after found for type java.util.Date

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I've been struggling with something for the last 2 days and can't fugure it up.
I'm using Java 7, Spring data jpa 1.0 and Hibernate 4.3.1.Final.
I'm trying to make a query that would fetch based on date. I've trimmed the code to make readable

All dates are java.util.Date

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class Informe {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="COMUNICACION_ID")
    private Comunicacion comunicacion;

    public Comunicacion getComunicacion() {
        return comunicacion;
    }

    public void setComunicacion(Comunicacion comunicacion) {
        this.comunicacion = comunicacion;
    }
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "REGISTRO_CALIFICACION")
public class RegistroCalificacion extends Informe {
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "COMUNICACION")
public class Comunicacion {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;
    @Basic
    @javax.persistence.Column(name = "FECHA_PUBLICACION_DESDE", nullable = false, insertable = true,     updatable = true, length = 19, precision = 0)
    private Date fechaPublicacionDesde;

    public Date getFechaPublicacionDesde() {
        return fechaPublicacionDesde;
    }

    public void setFechaPublicacionDesde(Date fechaPublicacionDesde) {
        this.fechaPublicacionDesde = fechaPublicacionDesde;
    }
}

public interface InformeRepository extends BaseRepository<Informe, Long> {
    List<RegistroCalificacion> findByComunicacionFechaPublicacionDesdeAfter(Date date);

}
```

This throws  this exception while creating the beans

```
Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property after found for type java.util.Date
```

But If I access directly to Comunicación, like below, it works fine.

```
public interface ComunicacionRepository extends BaseRepository<Comunicacion, Long> {

   List<Comunicacion> findByFechaPublicacionDesdeBefore(Date date);
}
```

I've tried using @Query and I get the same result.
Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you add the getter/setter as well, because I assume fetchacarga property is fechaPublicacionDesde.

Comment: Yes, sorry for that. I copied the wrong property, thanks for that. I've added the getter/setter

Comment: try to add getter/setter for Comunicacion in the Informe base class.

Comment: I have them in the code, I didn't put the getters/setters here to make it easier to read. There they are now.

Comment: Check my response. I think the repository didn't contain the source querying entity (the parent) but it was configured according to the projected destination entity (the child).

Answer (score 0):

I think this should be your repository:

```
public interface RegistroCalificacionRepository extends BaseRepository<RegistroCalificacion, Long> {

    List<Comunicacion> findByFechaPublicacionDesdeBefore(Date date);
}
```

Because you want the RegistroCalificacion to be queried not Comunicacion.

Comment: No, that won't work as I need a list of RegistroCalificacion, not Comunicacion

Answer (score 0):

Could you add

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)

@javax.persistence.Column(name = "FECHA_PUBLICACION_DESDE", nullable = false, insertable = true,     updatable = true, length = 19, precision = 0)
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date fechaPublicacionDesde;
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
public interface InformeRepository extends BaseRepository<Informe, Long> {
    List<RegistroCalificacion> findByComunicacionFechaPublicacionDesde(Date date);

}
```

You are adding the word "After" at the end of the name of your method, and the repository can not find a property named like that on your "Comunicacion" entity.